# the default svn status is recursively, how to svn status non-recursively?

Tags: svn

By default svn status would run recursively. How can I just `svn status` on the current directory?

eg.

> run 'svn status' on '/dir1', it would also check `/dir1/dir2`, `/dir1/dir2/dir3`, `/dir1/dir2a`, ..., actually what I need is only `/dir1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
svn status --depth files
```

> --depth ARG
>
> Instructs Subversion to limit the scope of an operation to a
>   particular tree depth. ARG is one of empty (only the target itself),
>   files (the target and any immediate file children thereof), immediates
>   (the target and any immediate children thereof), or infinity (the
>   target and all of its descendants—full recursion).

See [this document](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth) for more.